# Adding time stamps to memcached logging

Tags: logging, memcached, rhel5

Is it possible to add in time stamps to entries created by -v, -vv, or -vvv in memcached?

Currently my setup has -vv logging, and it's being written to file, but having a time stamp would be useful in case I need to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Use supervisord to run memcached, so that supervisord will put stderr of memcached through syslog (piping output of memcached to a file in /var/log isn't really logging), then rsyslog to a log aggrogator like Graylog2 which will add timestamps?